# Plot multiple parabolas with D3 or similar library

Tags: plot, d3.js, javascript, graphing

I am currently exploring the D3 library and it's tutorials. I've made histograms, bubble charts, and other traditional visualizations.

I am currently trying to plot several parabolas using D3. I have a CSV file that contains two x-intercepts, the vertex, and the "a" value for multiple parabolas. I was curious if anyone with experience with D3 has made a visualization where you have had to plot some sort of parabola.

Any information related to plotting parabolas (using x-intercepts and a coordinate point) would be helpful (D3 or not). THANKS.

Answer (score 0):

I would find a bunch of points on the parabola:

```
var points = [];
for (var x = 0; x < 500; x++){
  var y = a*(x - xIntercept1)*(x - xIntercept2);
  points.push({x: x, y: y});
}
```

and graph them with d3.svg.line() 
https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes